# BUSYBOX: How do I check if I have a 32 or a 64 architecture?

Tags: computer-architecture, busybox

I am on a Busybox and `uname –a` results: `Linux 3.14.28-1.12 #1 SMP Thu Jun 15 08:53:06 CEST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux`. Is this a 32 bit architecture or how can I check it?

Comment: This question has been answered on Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136519/52365

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your architecture is 32-bit.

Arm versions under armv8 are 32-bit, but not all versions 8 and over are 64-bit.

Also, you can check whether your system is 32-bit or 64-bit using:

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

Comment: Sorry, `getconf` is not known on BUSYBOX: `# getconf LONG_BIT` results to 
`-sh: getconf: not found`

Comment: Oh, I didn't check that, I just tested it on Ubuntu...